# Sql Server isn't closing a connection to linked Server after execution

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ibm-midrange

I am using a linked server to update records in AS/400. It isn't closing the connections properly. On the AS/400 side there are still a number of connections idle. In the sql log it is showing:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION writing address 0000000000000024 at 0x0000000077BDE4B4

It doesn't appear that it is every time we open a connection and update the file on the AS/400 side. We updated 222 records and there were still 210 connections open. I would expect there to be 222.

We are calling a stored procedure from a .NET app. In the stored procedure we are executing:

EXECUTE (@as400Query) at S100405D

Where the as400Query is a string with the update statement and S100405D is the linked server. The records are getting updated in the AS/400, so that isn't an issue. Just seems that when trying to close the connections, there is an error. Also I checked the settings on the linked server and the connection timeout = 0 (off). Not sure if setting a timeout will close them, or it won't matter because it is throwing an error anyways.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Brian

Comment: You updated 222 records, closed the connections, but expected to see 222 open connections? Either I'm missing something or there is an error in your question?

Answer (score 1):

are you submiting any sort of code to close the connection on the AS side? SQL server will only close its connecion, any other connection opened on any other RDBMS won't be managed by SQL

Answer (score 0):

As an IBM i programmer, I would not expect to see any errors during a stored procedure call.  Rarely, the OS will throw an exception if there is a parameter mis-match.  The most common is the caller (C#) using VARCHAR and the IBM side declaring it as CHAR.

Aside from that, have the IBM people make sure they are current on PTFs.

As a style matter, I would not expect to see:

```
open connection
CALL proc
close connection
```

for each row to be updated.  Rather, I would expect

```
open connection
loop
  CALL proc
end loop
close connection
```

Comment: There was a mismatch in the type and I changed it. Still didn't solve the issue. WHat is puzzling is that if we call the as400 222 time, there are 210 connections left. I would expect 222. Seems like it is closing some of them, but not very many until it runs into problems.

Comment: Which issue isn't solved?  Is an exception still being thrown?  I'm not a .NET programmer, so I'm trying to help with the exception on the IBM side.  From the C# side, I would expect a CLOSE for each OPEN and am a bit surprised that any connections are left open after 222 calls.